# Mongo Import - Failed: fields '' and '.' are incompatible

Tags: mongodb, hadoop, sqoop

I'm importing external data from Oracle to HDFS using Sqoop, after that I'm trying to import it to MongDB, follow the command that I'm usign and the error message:

-- Import external file to HDFS

```
sqoop import \
--connect "jdbc:oracle:thin:@(description=(address=(protocol=tcp)(host=hostname)(port=1521))(connect_data=(service_name=SID)))" \
--username user --table schema. my_table \
--num-mappers 1 --verbose -P

--Import HDFS file to MongoDB
hadoop fs -text /user/cloudera/mytable/part* | mongoimport -d database -c my_table --type csv --headerline
```

**Error:**

> mongoimport: /usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.10: no version information
>   available (required by mongoimport) mongoimport:
>   /usr/lib64/libssl.so.10: no version information available (required by
>   mongoimport) 2015-12-08T07:08:24.001-0800 Failed: fields '' and '.'
>   are incompatible 2015-12-08T07:08:24.001-0800 imported 0 documents
>   text: Unable to write to output stream.